# How to interact with the elements on the next page after I log in?

Tags: excel, vba

I have my Excel VBA macro logging into my site and from the landing I direct it to a search page.

After IE gets to the search page I'm getting
[image]

I thought resetting the objcollection on the new page would work but I don't know how to set focus or select the new page.

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest2()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://example.login.aspx"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName

'Set appIE = Nothing
appIE.Document.getElementById("txtUsername").Value = "user"
appIE.Document.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "Pass"
appIE.Document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.Navigate "https://example.Search.aspx"

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName
*appIE.Document.getElementById("txtNum").Value = "0000000"*
appIE.Document.getElementById("btnSearch").Click
End Sub
```

I changed to this and it worked. The elements were in an iframe.

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest2()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://example.login.aspx"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName

'Set appIE = Nothing
appIE.Document.getElementById("txtUsername").Value = "user"
appIE.Document.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "Pass"
appIE.Document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.Navigate "https://example.Search.aspx"

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set doc = appIE.Document
Set iframeDoc = doc.frames("EncJump").Document
iframeDoc.getElementById("txtNum").Value = "0000000"
iframeDoc.getElementById("btnSearch").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur? It may be that you need to wait for an element to become present, or an element resides within a frame/iframe or even in another window if you have a pop-up. Additionally, using the snippet tool via [edit] is good for sharing relevant HTML to aid with diagnosing any problems with element selection.

Comment: The one with the asterisks 3rd to the last. I assume after I nave to the new page I need to update a collection or object with the new element IDs so I can focus on them. I would provide the HTML but I can't I would probably get in trouble for posting it.

Comment: You aren't referencing a collection on the error  line. It is possible as I said above that you need to wait for the element to be present with a timed loop to prevent infinite looping, or you may need to negotiate a parent frame/iframe. If you open dev tools you can highlight the relevant element in the html and then search to see if it is contained within a parent iframe/frame tag. You don't appear to use the collection at all. If there were a problem with referencing a stale collection you would most likely get a permission denied message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are unable to post the HTML, this is more speculation than anything. There are 2 likely issues:

1. Your issue is related to an iframe - which if this is the case there's not much we can do without seeing the HTML.
2. Your issue is that your element hasn't fully loaded (yes, happens even if readystate = complete).

So Change the line giving you issues to:

```
dim startTime as single
starttime = timer

on error resume next
do while appIE.Document.getElementById("txtNum") is nothing
    if timer - starttime > 10 then       'Change 10 to # of max seconds to wait
        msgbox "Element didn't load! Check internet connection, aborting"
        exit sub
    else
        doevents
    end if
loop
on error goto 0
appIE.Document.getElementById("txtNum").Value = "0000000"
```

To build on point # 1 - You can think of an iFrame as it's own document. Usually you will see a the tagname `<iframe>`. You will need to use that object's document (I usually set it equal to `iframe.contentdocument`) and then proceed as normal.

Comment: Good point. Just added `exit sub` instead of `is not`. Thanks @QHarr

Comment: You were 100% right it was an iframe.
I got it working and added the changes after my original post